# If a class has a property of another class, how to tell if the properties of the inner class match

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm working on a solution for being able to see if 2 objects are a match. All that matters is that for the 2 objects, if they share a property, the values of those properties are a match

For the two classes SC and DI, the Test property correctly evaluate to True. But the Little class will evaluate to false since SC and DI use different instances of the Little object, even though the information of the Little class is correct.

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;

    public class Little
    {
        public string L1 { get; set; }
        public string L2 { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Solution
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Test { get; set; }
        public Little L {get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Device
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Test { get; set; }
        public Little L {get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Li = new Little {
                L1 = "L1111",
                L2 = "L2222"
            };
            var Li2 = new Little {
                L1 = "L1111",
                L2 = "L2222"
            };
            var SC = new Solution {
                Name = "SC",
                Test = "T1",
                L = Li2
            };
            var DI = new Device {
                Name = "DI",
                Test = "T1",
                L = Li
            };
            
            foreach (var property in SC.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var deviceProperty = DI.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);
                if (deviceProperty != null)
                {
                    if (deviceProperty.GetValue(DI) != property.GetValue(SC))
                    {
                        // it is registered as flase since DI and SC have different Little objects - even though thouse object values are the same 
                        // Best way to determine if the values are of type Little (or any other me-defined class) - because wont .IsClass evaluate string to True as well?
                        // What if there was another class inside Litte? Do I have to recursively / loop until I can see everything is a string or int?
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("We have a match");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetValue returns an `object`, call a ToString() and then do "string comparison". As it is, your code compares two objects and so doesn't match.
If you expect properties of different types, then you need to override `Equals` to do custom comparison.